# How to do this in LINQ or EF.Core?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have a application with 3 models (class).
All models have some type of relationship, like below:

User -> Group -> Database

A better explanation:

- *User*: a class where store username, password, etc, and every group that the user belongs... So, one user can have **one or more** *Group*.
- *Group*: story only the group name, and **database** that this group have access. A group can have **one or more** databases, and have **one or more** *Users*.
- *Database*: store connection's property to a database.

Transforming this to class, maybe it's something like this:

```
class User {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

class Group {
  public int Id { get; set; }  
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<User> Users { get; set; } /* inverse */
  public List<Database> Databases { get; set; }
}

class Database {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Hostname { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string DbName { get; set; }
  public List<Group> Groups { get; set; } /* inverse */
}
```

So, now the real problem.

Suppose that I have only the Id of the user, nothing more, and I like to list all databases that the user have access, so, I must list all groups that the user have access, then in every group, I must list every databases that the group have access.

It's possible to make this in LINQ in a "direct" way? Or using EF.Core (again, "direct" way)?

Or it's better a more "long" way, like I describe above?

```
var user = _context.user.code_to_get_user_by_id(id);
var groups = _context.user.code_to_get_all_groups();
var databases = groups.code_to_get_all_databases();

foreach (var group in groups) {
  // do something
}
```

This is just a simple example. My real application have 4 class, with some different relationships and much more properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MSDN Enumerable.SelectMany Example**

```
class PetOwner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<String> Pets { get; set; }
}

public static void SelectManyEx1()
{
    PetOwner[] petOwners = 
        { new PetOwner { Name="Higa, Sidney", 
              Pets = new List<string>{ "Scruffy", "Sam" } },
          new PetOwner { Name="Ashkenazi, Ronen", 
              Pets = new List<string>{ "Walker", "Sugar" } },
          new PetOwner { Name="Price, Vernette", 
              Pets = new List<string>{ "Scratches", "Diesel" } } };

    // Query using SelectMany().
    IEnumerable<string> query1 = petOwners.SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets);

    Console.WriteLine("Using SelectMany():");

    // Only one foreach loop is required to iterate 
    // through the results since it is a
    // one-dimensional collection.
    foreach (string pet in query1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pet);
    }

    // This code shows how to use Select() 
    // instead of SelectMany().
    IEnumerable<List<String>> query2 =
        petOwners.Select(petOwner => petOwner.Pets);

    Console.WriteLine("\nUsing Select():");

    // Notice that two foreach loops are required to 
    // iterate through the results
    // because the query returns a collection of arrays.
    foreach (List<String> petList in query2)
    {
        foreach (string pet in petList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pet);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 Using SelectMany():
 Scruffy
 Sam
 Walker
 Sugar
 Scratches
 Diesel

 Using Select():
 Scruffy
 Sam

 Walker
 Sugar

 Scratches
 Diesel
*/
```

**DotNetPearls SelectMany Example**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // Input.
    string[] array =
    {
    "dot",
    "net",
    "perls"
    };

    // Convert each string in the string array to a character array.
    // ... Then combine those character arrays into one.
    var result = array.SelectMany(element => element.ToCharArray());

    // Display letters.
    foreach (char letter in result)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(letter);
    }
  }
}

/* 
Output:

d
o 
t 
n 
e 
t 
p 
e 
r 
l 
s

*/
```

You can use LINQ SelectMany function. Check these links.

[MSDN Select Many](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Examples of DotNetPearls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/selectmany)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Link-only answers are not recommended and likely to be removed by the review process. This is because sooner or later the links will break, making the answer useless. Try to write some code that answers the question.

Comment: e.g. after getting your user, `var userDBs = user.Groups.SelectMany(y => y.Databases)`

Comment: resolved using the following code: `var bds = users.Where(u => u.Id == 1).SelectMany(g => g.Groups).SelectMany(d => d.Databases).GroupBy(d => d.Id).ToList();`